# how to place 5 cols of different width using grid?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-grid

I'm new to grid layouts. I have always used flex but for making a tabular structure like shown in the pic, I suppose grid would be best. But I'm having trouble in adjusting the width of each col.

output ss:
[image]

my code:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-12 w-full">
   <div className="col-span-1">Flag</div>
   <div className="col-span-2">Name</div>
   <div className="col-span-2">Population</div>
   <div className="col-span-2">Area (km²)</div>
   <div className="col-span-2">Region</div>
</div>
```

But this leaves extra space at the end and changing to col-span-3 pushes the last col to next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by default in [tailwindcss grids](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns) are `1fr` each, thereby leading to same sized grids, but in your case I'm assuming that *(based on your output ss)* you just need 5 columns only and not 12. Thereby replacing `grid-cols-12` to `grid-cols-5` for a equi-width `<div>`. But in order to control the width of each `<div>` you can specify it manually using a custom tailwindcss className like `grid-cols-[1fr,3fr,2fr,2fr,2fr]`. Here the five values will control each `div` respectively *(you can also use other values like px,rem,%,vw...)*. So change those values accordingly to get your desired output. Also if you want spacing between your div and not in each end use `gap-(desiredValue)`.

*p.s. `fr` is a fractional unit and `1fr` is for 1 part of the available space.*